# Is it OK to ask very specific question about Toshiba's ac100 (ARM smartbook)?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have one of the beautiful Toshiba ac100s. Is it within the scope of askubuntu.com to ask specific questions here? It will be very technical, for example how to get one specific kernel-version for one specific sub-model working (how to compile, set up etc). It's developed in IRC for now and highly experimental (==fun).

Comment: Maybe you should use [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not subjective, not off topic, not a duplicate, not spam, not geographically limited and certainly not offensive. Thus, it doesn't fit any reason not to belong here ;)

Answer (score 9):

Sure, I don't see why not, if you're trailblazing with the laptop might as well document it here.